# How to properly index multiple left joins

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query :-

```
SELECT `challan` . * , `accounts`.`Name` AS `Account` , 
`accounts`.`AddLine1` , `accounts`.`AddLine2` , `accounts`.`TIN` , 
`accounts`.`PAN` , `accounts2`.`Name` AS `TempoName` , `items`.`Name` AS 
`Item` , `items`.`Units` , `items`.`SecondaryUnits` , 
`goods_received`.`Type` , `accounts3`.`Name` AS `Party`
FROM `challan`
LEFT JOIN `accounts` ON `challan`.`Account_Id` = `accounts`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN `accounts` AS `accounts2` ON `challan`.`TempoId` =`accounts2`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN `items` ON `challan`.`Item_Id` = `items`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN `goods_received` ON `challan`.`ItemGoodsReceivedId` = `goods_received`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN `accounts` AS `accounts3` ON `goods_received`.`AccountId` = `accounts3`.`Id`
WHERE `Challan_Id` = 'EBpzQD'
```

I want to properly index this query so that it runs faster. I propose to add an index on the following :-

`accounts`.`Id` (this is a primary key),

`items`.`Id` (this is a primary key),

`goods_received`.`Id` (this is a primary key),

`challan`.`Account_Id`,

`challan`.`TempoId`,

`challan`.`Item_Id`,

`goods_received`.`AccountId`,

`challan`.`ItemGoodsReceivedId`

Please tell if I am right in the approach or I have to add more indexes.

Comment: can you show the data example and output example you want achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two left joins, and the fifth, require the existing primary key index on  accounts.Id - you do not need to add a new index.

The third join requires the existing primary key index on items.Id - you do not need to add a new index.

The fourth join requires the existing primary key index on goods_received.Id - you do not need to add a new index.

You don't tell us which table the column Challen_Id belongs to, but I assume that it is the challen table. That column also needs an index for the WHERE clause to be efficient.

The other indexes you mention are not necessary for this query. However, it's always good practise to ensure you have an index (usually non-unique) on every foreign key. This avoids the need for a table scan when deleting or updating the corresponding candidate key. You might not need it if you don't do that or your data is small.

Finally, a stylistic point. You do not need to use the backtick apostrophes around any of these names, as none of the characters are special.

Comment: OP specified that \`id\` is PRIMARY KEY of \`goods_received\`. Addition of "covering indexes" might be of benefit for some of the tables, if the table rows are very long.  OP should use `EXPLAIN` to see query execution plan, to see which indexes are being used.

Comment: Right you are, I missed that. Updated my answer. However, the need for covering indexes has nothing to do with the row size, but the total table size. I updated that also.

Comment: A covering index allows the query to be satisfied from the index, without lookups to pages in the underlying table. If the rows in the underlying table are "large", that's fewer rows per block. If the covering index includes a subset of the table columns that comprises a significantly smaller row, that's more rows per index block,

Comment: Ok, but that's not the reason I suggested indexing foreign keys. If I have a large table with a foreign key, and I delete a row from the referenced table, the large table must be scanned to find records that reference the deleted row (to delete or nullify the FKs). With an index, that's not a full table scan. Got bitten by this in production once, never again.